# Is there a way to disable "MDN References Intellisense" popup (for HTML & CSS) in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is in reference to disabling [this specific feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_38#_mdn-reference-for-html-and-css), while leaving all other code hinting features active.

I am very familiar with the Settings GUI as well as settings.json and have searched extensively but none of the Intellisense/hints/suggestions configuration seems to apply to this particular popup.

[image: Annotated screenshot indicating the popup I wish to disable]

Answer (score 113):

1. Just going to `Code` -> `Preferences` -> `Settings`
2. Search "*editor hover enabled*" and ***disable*** checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, that feature has been doing my head in and I couldn't find what it was called :\

Comment: This actually turns hover off completely; so I found changing "editor hover delay" to 3000 (3 seconds) curbed my frustration. If you still want the tooltip, just have to wait for it.

Comment: As dean.huczok mentions, setting the delay to 3000 also works best for me. I 've unintentionally clicked the MDM link inside the popup way too many times because it showed up too fast. Terrible Microsoft UX, as usual.

Comment: Agree it's bad UX. The link pops up exactly where I'm trying to type. I found that increasing the delay to 500 and unchecking the "Editor > Hover:Above" prevents me from unintentionally clicking the MDM link.

Comment: He asked for MDN reference only!

Answer (score 49):

It looks like it will finally be in v1.52 for html files, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97979 - it is coming to css/scss files as well.

Two new settings:

```
"html.hover.documentation": false,
"html.hover.references": false,
```

The `references` one will disable the `MDN Reference` link only.  The `documentation` setting all the MDN documentation as well.

```
"html.hover.documentation": "Show tag and attribute documentation in hover.",
"html.hover.references": "Show references to MDN in hover."
```

---

And for v1.54 extending to css, scss and less:

> #### Hovers in CSS/LESS/SCSS and HTML
>
> You can now fine tune the content of hovers in HTML and CSS:
>
> - Do not show documentation from MDN
> - Do not show the link to the MDN page Use the settings `css.hover.documentation` and `css.hover.references` resp the similar
>   settings in `html`, `css`, `scss` and `less`

from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_54.md#hovers-in-csslessscss-and-html

Comment: oh man thank you.  Why on earth would you want an mdn reference on every single line of code

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Wanted to disable reference on hover for only HTML tags.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on *.vue files. Why isn't there a global setting without distinguishing file extensions?

Comment: Need to restart VS code after applying these settings.

Comment: @AdamJagosz have you found a solution for vue files? It's really annoying :O

Comment: @"kater louis" I just disabled Editor › Hover: Sticky altogether. This causes the popup to disappear as soon as mouse is hovered onto it and I'm happily unable to click anything that pops up at me.

Comment: Just know this wont work for PHP files. It'll still show the HTML hovers =/

Comment: It does not work if you are using styled components on ts files

Answer (score 38):

Go to `File > Preferences > Settings`

*or*

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

Search `MDN` and you will see 4 check boxes there.
uncheck those and you are good to go:

[image: 4 check-boxes]

In this way, you can still have the hover explanations about certain tags and keywords but only the MDN reference link will be gone:

[image: explanations]

Comment: the accurate solution

Answer (score 12):

Found this, in `settings.json` insert the following. It might turn off more than you wanted, but at least that pop up will be gone.

```
"editor.hover.enabled": false,
```

To find `settings.json` (the right one), open VSCode and push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. Type "settings.json" and make sure you open up the one in AppData (or wherever you installed VSCode in).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's something I already had in place and doesn't solve when typing new code the hinting appears with the MDN Reference box still beside it.

Answer (score 1):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> looking for the settings.json file it will show you two of them, Open Default settings.json and Open settings.json.
you should paste this:

```
- "editor.hover.enabled": false,
```

on the Open settings.json.

The default settings.json is not editable.

Comment: that's worked for me thank you :)