# Remove MDN references from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I stop the MDN references tooltips from appearing in my Visual Studio Code editor window? I'd like to turn them off and I'm unable to find any settings to adjust them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to disable "MDN References Intellisense" popup (for HTML & CSS) in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162276/is-there-a-way-to-disable-mdn-references-intellisense-popup-for-html-css-i). See also [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80894).

Comment: Thank you!
Adding this line to the settings.json file removed the MDN References:
"editor.hover.enabled": false

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65083602/836330 for the new settings about this.