# How do I disable ONLY the MDN reference tooltip suggestions in VS Code? I want to leave all other suggestions on - i.e I do NOT want to disable hover

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have seen this mentioned in other questions (mainly here:
[Is there a way to disable "MDN References Intellisense" popup (for HTML & CSS) in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162276/is-there-a-way-to-disable-mdn-references-intellisense-popup-for-html-css-i)) but that hasn't addressed my specific issue. Whenever I type one or 2 letters in any code file I get a LOAD of unrelated 'shortcuts' to various 'interfaces' that are referenced in MDN. For example:

[image]

and:

[image]

This just adds visual noise in my opinion, is distracting, and I would really like to disable ALL (and only) MDN reference tooltips/shortcuts. I do NOT want to completely disable the hover feature as I find it useful.

Is there any way of doing this?

**EDIT: I have since found the solution. My answer is at the bottom of this post.**

Comment: sorry. I didn't read carefully and misunderstood the question. what about https://stackoverflow.com/q/73364860/11107541 ?

Comment: All good, I have found the solution anyway. I have posted it as an answer to this problem....

Answer (score 0):

deactivate the hover references you don't want from this list in settings.json

```json
{   
    "html.hover.references": false,
    "css.hover.references": false,
    "less.hover.references": false,
    "scss.hover.references": false,
    "html.hover.documentation": false,
    "css.hover.documentation": false,
    "less.hover.documentation": false,
    "scss.hover.documentation": false
}
```

or you can search `mdn` in settings and click the checkbox.

[image: settings.json]

Comment: please don't answer duplicates. vote to close them.

Comment: I have all of the above set to false, as well as turned off the checkbox for HTML in the settings mentioned above and it has had no effect I'm afraid...

Comment: Did you restart?

Comment: Try adding `html.hover.documentation: false`  all the same language prefixes as above can set these attributes

Comment: The above didnt work but I did FIND a solution:  "typescript.suggest.enabled": true into settings.json turns it off....

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to find a solution:

You need to add:

`"typescript.suggest.enabled": false,`

to settings.json, alternatively you need need to turn off this checkbox in settings:

[image]

Comment: this is a ... rather nuclear solution.

Comment: @starball yes as soon as I posted this I went back and noticed that whilst all my snippets and shortcuts were appearing, auto complete on things like TS objects had gone. So it solves one problem and then creates another..... All a bit of learning curve for me!