how do i make this go away?
pic of MDN reference that will not go away
someone PLEASE tell me how to make this go away!! I'm about to just give up vs code altogether!
I have turned off all suggestions, all hover suggestions, auto completions, IntelliSense references, you name it, I've turned it off! but these "MDN references" keep popping up anyway & I seriously can't take it anymore - it's like they're mocking me. please help
!!! also, it's only when I'm in a jsx file. & it only started happening after the latest update

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77219543/how-do-i-disable-only-the-mdn-reference-tooltip-suggestions-in-vs-code-i-want-t
